# Laravel Inertia js & vue js

Tags: php, vue.js, controller, inertiajs

I am trying to make a delete button for my Laravel 8 app. I got some errors while doing that and don't know how to do it.

My app is about creating training courses for students and for each training course they will get a YouTube video created by an admin and I am trying to add the delete formation function.

That is my controller I tried to create a delete function. My update, create functions work fine but the delete doesn't work and I get the following error message:

> [Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'course' of undefined"

![Error message screenshot][1]

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\Episode;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreCourseWithEpisodes;

class CourseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $courses = Course::with('user')
        ->select('courses.*', DB::raw(
            '(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id))
            FROM completions
            INNER JOIN episodes ON completions.episode_id = episodes.id
            WHERE episodes.course_id = courses.id
            ) AS participants'
        ))->addSelect(DB::raw(
            '(SELECT SUM(duration)
            FROM episodes
            WHERE episodes.course_id = courses.id
            ) AS total_duration'
        ))
        ->withCount('episodes')->latest()->paginate(5);

        return Inertia::render('Courses/Index', [
            'courses' => $courses
        ]);
    }

    public function show(int $id)
    {
        $course = Course::where('id', $id)->with('episodes')->first();
        $watched = auth()->user()->episodes;

        return Inertia::render('Courses/Show', [
            'course' => $course,
            'watched' => $watched
        ]);
    }

    public function store(StoreCourseWithEpisodes $request)
    {
        $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;

        $course = Course::create($request->all());

        foreach($request->input('episodes') as $episode)
        {
            $episode['course_id'] = $course->id;
            Episode::create($episode);
        }

        return Redirect::route('courses.index')->with('success', 'Félicitations, votre formation a bien été postée.');
    }

    public function edit(int $id)
    {
        $course = Course::where('id', $id)->with('episodes')->first();
        $this->authorize('update', $course);

        return Inertia::render('Courses/Edit', [
            'course' => $course
        ]);
    }

    public function update(StoreCourseWithEpisodes $request)
    {
        $course = Course::where('id', $request->id)->first();
        $this->authorize('update', $course);
        $course->update($request->all());
        $course->episodes()->delete();

        foreach($request->episodes as $episode) {
            $episode['course_id'] = $course->id;
            Episode::create($episode);
        }

        return Redirect::route('courses.index')->with('success', 'Félicitations, votre formation a bien été modifiée.');
    }

    public function toggleProgress(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('episodeId');
        $user = auth()->user();

        $user->episodes()->toggle($id);

        return $user->episodes;
    }

    public function delete(StoreCourseWithEpisodes $request ,$id)
    {
        $course = Course::find($id);
     
        $course->episodes()->delete();
        // $request->has('id') ?
        //     Article::find($request->input('id'))->delete() :
        //     redirect()->back()
        //         ->with('errors', 'Attentions.');

        return Redirect::route('courses.index')->with('success', 'Félicitations, votre formation a bien été supprimer.');

    }
}
```

That is my vue where I have to call my delete function:

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <template #header>
            Liste des formations
        </template>
        <section class="py-6">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div v-if="$page.flash.success" class="bg-green-200 text-green-600 p-4">
                {{ $page.flash.success }}
            </div>
                <div class="py-3" v-for="course in courses.data" v-bind:key="course.id">
                    <div class="bg-white rounded shadow p-4">
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500 flex justify-between items-center">
                        <div>
                            Mise en ligne par <strong>{{ course.user.name }}</strong> (<span class="text-gray-500 text-sm">{{ course.participants }} participant<span v-if="parseInt(course.participants) > 1 ">s</span>)
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="block text-sm text-gray-400">{{ course.episodes_count }} épisode<span v-if="course.episodes_count > 1">s</span></span>
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="text-3xl">{{ course.title }}</h1>
                        <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700">
                            {{ convert(course.total_duration) }}</span>
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500 mt-2">{{ course.description }}</div>
                        <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
                            <a :href="'course/' + course.id" class="bg-indigo-700 text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm mt-3 inline-block rounded hover:bg-indigo-500">Voir la formation</a>
                            <a :href="'courses/edit/' + course.id" v-if="course.update" class="bg-gray-700 text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm mt-3 inline-block rounded hover:bg-gray-500">Editer</a>
                             <button @click="remove(course.id)"
                                        class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                    Supprimer
                                </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <inertia-link :href="link.url" class="text-indigo-700 border-gray-500 p-5" v-for="link in courses.links" v-bind:key="link.label">
                    <span v-bind:class="{'text-red-700' : link.active}">{{ link.label }}</span>
                </inertia-link>
            </div>
        </section>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>

import AppLayout from './../../Layouts/AppLayout';

export default {
    components: {
        AppLayout
    },

    props: ['courses'],
   data() {
            return {
                courseData: this.courses
            }
        },

    methods: {
  remove() {
                this.$inertia.delete('/courses/delete/'+ this.courseData.id, this.courseData);
            },
        // deleteRow(id) {
        //                 this.$inertia.delete('/article/delete/' + id)
                        
        //     },
        convert(timestamps) {
            let hours = Math.floor(timestamps / 3600);
            let minutes = Math.floor(timestamps / 60) - (hours * 60);
            let seconds = timestamps % 60;

            return hours.toString().padStart(2, 0) + ':' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, 0) + ':' + seconds.toString().padStart(2, 0);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

[enter image description here][2]
here is my vue with no error but my delete button still does not work

```
<template>
    <app-layout>
        <template #header>
            Liste des formations
        </template>
        <section class="py-6">
            <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div v-if="$page.flash.success" class="bg-green-200 text-green-600 p-4">
                {{ $page.flash.success }}
            </div>
                <div class="py-3" v-for="course in courses.data" v-bind:key="course.id">
                    <div class="bg-white rounded shadow p-4">
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500 flex justify-between items-center">
                        <div>
                            Mise en ligne par <strong>{{ course.user.name }}</strong> (<span class="text-gray-500 text-sm">{{ course.participants }} participant<span v-if="parseInt(course.participants) > 1 ">s</span>)
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <span class="block text-sm text-gray-400">{{ course.episodes_count }} épisode<span v-if="course.episodes_count > 1">s</span></span>
                        </div>
                        <h1 class="text-3xl">{{ course.title }}</h1>
                        <span class="inline-block bg-gray-200 rounded-full px-3 py-1 text-sm font-semibold text-gray-700">
                            {{ convert(course.total_duration) }}</span>
                        <div class="text-sm text-gray-500 mt-2">{{ course.description }}</div>
                        <div class="flex justify-between items-center">
                            <a :href="'course/' + course.id" class="bg-indigo-700 text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm mt-3 inline-block rounded hover:bg-indigo-500">Voir la formation</a>
                            <a :href="'courses/edit/' + course.id" v-if="course.update" class="bg-gray-700 text-white px-3 py-2 text-sm mt-3 inline-block rounded hover:bg-gray-500">Editer</a>
                             <button @click="remove()"
                                        class="bg-red-500 hover:bg-red-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded">
                                    Supprimer
                                </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </section>
    </app-layout>
</template>

<script>

import AppLayout from './../../Layouts/AppLayout';

export default {
    components: {
        AppLayout
    },

    props: ['courses'],
   data() {
            return {
                courseData: this.courses
            }
        },

    methods: {
  remove(id) {
                this.$inertia.delete('/courses/delete/'+ id);
            },
        // deleteRow(id) {
        //                 this.$inertia.delete('/article/delete/' + id)
                        
        //     },
        convert(timestamps) {
            let hours = Math.floor(timestamps / 3600);
            let minutes = Math.floor(timestamps / 60) - (hours * 60);
            let seconds = timestamps % 60;

            return hours.toString().padStart(2, 0) + ':' + minutes.toString().padStart(2, 0) + ':' + seconds.toString().padStart(2, 0);
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

and my controller right here

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Inertia\Inertia;
use App\Models\Course;
use App\Models\Episode;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreCourseWithEpisodes;

class CourseController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $courses = Course::with('user')
        ->select('courses.*', DB::raw(
            '(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(user_id))
            FROM completions
            INNER JOIN episodes ON completions.episode_id = episodes.id
            WHERE episodes.course_id = courses.id
            ) AS participants'
        ))->addSelect(DB::raw(
            '(SELECT SUM(duration)
            FROM episodes
            WHERE episodes.course_id = courses.id
            ) AS total_duration'
        ))
        ->withCount('episodes')->latest()->paginate(5);

        return Inertia::render('Courses/Index', [
            'courses' => $courses
        ]);
    }

    public function show(int $id)
    {
        $course = Course::where('id', $id)->with('episodes')->first();
        $watched = auth()->user()->episodes;

        return Inertia::render('Courses/Show', [
            'course' => $course,
            'watched' => $watched
        ]);
    }

    public function store(StoreCourseWithEpisodes $request)
    {
        $user_id = \Auth::user()->id;

        $course = Course::create($request->all());

        foreach($request->input('episodes') as $episode)
        {
            $episode['course_id'] = $course->id;
            Episode::create($episode);
        }

        return Redirect::route('courses.index')->with('success', 'Félicitations, votre formation a bien été postée.');
    }

    public function edit(int $id)
    {
        $course = Course::where('id', $id)->with('episodes')->first();
        $this->authorize('update', $course);

        return Inertia::render('Courses/Edit', [
            'course' => $course
        ]);
    }

    public function update(StoreCourseWithEpisodes $request)
    {
        $course = Course::where('id', $request->id)->first();
        $this->authorize('update', $course);
        $course->update($request->all());
        $course->episodes()->delete();

        foreach($request->episodes as $episode) {
            $episode['course_id'] = $course->id;
            Episode::create($episode);
        }

        return Redirect::route('courses.index')->with('success', 'Félicitations, votre formation a bien été modifiée.');
    }

    public function toggleProgress(Request $request)
    {
        $id = $request->input('episodeId');
        $user = auth()->user();

        $user->episodes()->toggle($id);

        return $user->episodes;
    }

    public function delete(StoreCourseWithEpisodes $request ,$id)
    {
        // dd($id);

        Course::find($id)->delete(); 
            
        // $course->episodes()->delete();
        // $request->has('id') ?
        //     Article::find($request->input('id'))->delete() :
        //     redirect()->back()
        //         ->with('errors', 'Attentions.');

        return Redirect::route('courses.index')->with('success', 'Félicitations, votre formation a bien été supprimer.');

    }
}
```

Comment: The error in the image seems to be on another Vue component. It's trying to reed a property course on a variable but there's no course property on the Vue component you posted.

Comment: Yeah Thanks i did change the component that bugging my vue but the delete button still doesn't work and i dont know why ```code